# Need to add security-realms in Wildfly 26

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-21, wildfly-26

I am migrating from Wildfly 21 to Wildfly 26.1.0

I need to add

```
<management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
    <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
        <server-identities>
            <ssl>
                <keystore path="application.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password" alias="server" key-password="password" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
            </ssl>
        </server-identities>
        <authentication>
            <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
            <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
        </authorization>
    </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
</management>
```

But it is not allowing me to add.

Is there any other way to add these in Wildfly 26.1.0

Answer (score 0):

it is now replaced by this snippet:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:15.0" final-providers="combined-providers" disallowed-providers="OracleUcrypto">
            <providers>
                <aggregate-providers name="combined-providers">
                    <providers name="elytron"/>
                    <providers name="openssl"/>
                </aggregate-providers>
                <provider-loader name="elytron" module="org.wildfly.security.elytron"/>
                <provider-loader name="openssl" module="org.wildfly.openssl"/>
            </providers>
            <audit-logging>
                <file-audit-log name="local-audit" path="audit.log" relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" format="JSON"/>
            </audit-logging>
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="ManagementDomain" default-realm="ManagementRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                    <realm name="ManagementRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                    <realm name="local" role-mapper="super-user-mapper"/>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="ApplicationDomain" default-realm="ApplicationRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                    <realm name="ApplicationRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                    <realm name="local"/>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
            <security-realms>
                <identity-realm name="local" identity="$local"/>
                <properties-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                    <users-properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/>
                    <groups-properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </properties-realm>
                <properties-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                    <users-properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                    <groups-properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </properties-realm>
            </security-realms>
            .
            .
            .
```

You can find the documentation about it [here](https://docs.wildfly.org/26/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html).