Wildfly - Accessing keystore file from host VM when running wildfly cli command in wildfly 26
I used to use wildfly 14 and used to setup keystore file using the following command in wildfly CLI
/core-service=management/security-realm=ApplicationRealm/server-identity=ssl:write-attribute(name=keystore-path,value="/path/to/keystore.jks")
But, now that I am migrating to wildfly 26, security-relam has been depricated and I was asked to use elytron per documentation.
By following the documentation, I came up with the following command.
/subsystem=elytron/key-store=httpsKS:add(path="/path/to/keystore.jks", credential-reference={clear-text=${env.KEY_TOKEN:password}})

But, this keeps complaining that the file does not exist at that location, Nothing really changed from the file location or permissions perspective. I was able to aceess it in wildfly 14, but unable to do so in the new elytron command in wildfly 26.
Is there something in the upgrade that is restricting me from accessing a file from host VM direclty and what would be my alternative to access it.
I tried to retrive the file from host VM but I keep getting file does not exist warning when I execute the wildfly cli file.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71943891/need-to-add-security-realms-in-wildfly-26
